# Help in compiling pdfrender library

Tags: android, android-ndk, pdfrenderer

I have a problem in compiling project

```
http://code.google.com/p/droidreader
```

When I compile in eclipse using NDK ,NDK doesnt compile because it says it cannot find fitz.h
even though its in directory where it should be and thus i cant compile to get a pdfrender library to use it in rendering pdf 
Can any body please help me compiling those files to get the library or if he has that library give it to me ?